# Rails Edit/Update action not working with nested models (has_many :through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, has-many-through, collection-select

The edit/update actions doesn't work.

I have three models:

document.rb

```
belongs_to :languages
has_many :configuration_documents
has_many :document_catalogs, through: :configuration_documents

accepts_nested_attributes_for :document_catalogs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :configuration_documents
```

document_catalog.rb

```
has_many :configuration_documents
has_many :documents, through: :configuration_documents
```

configuration_document.rb

```
belongs_to :document
belongs_to :document_catalog
```

This is my `new` method on documents_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @document = Document.new
    @all_documents = DocumentCatalog.all
    @configuration_document = @document.configuration_documents.build
  end
```

**This is my create method on documents_controller.rb version 1 (With this code, I can create the document).**

```
   def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)

    params[:document_catalogs][:id].each_line do |document|
      if !document.empty?
       @document.configuration_documents.build(:document_catalog_id => document)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_document_path(@document), notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Using the code above for create, I have this error when I try to** ***Edit***:

```
undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass on `<%= fields_for (@configuration_document) do |dc|%>`
```

**This is my code for create action on documents_controller version 2:**

```
    def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    if params[:document_catalogs][:id]
      params[:document_catalogs][:id] = params[:document_catalogs][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
      params[:document_catalogs][:id].each do |document|
        @miniature.configuration_documents.build(:document_catalogs_id => document)
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_document_path(@document), notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Note: When I use the code above for the update, even the "new" doesn't work and I got this error on the create action:**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `reject' for "2":String:
params[:document_catalogs][:id] = params[:document_catalogs][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
```

**This is my update method on documents_controller.rb:**

```
 def update
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    if params[:document_catalogs][:id]
      params[:document_catalogs][:id] = params[:document_catalogs][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
      old_documents_catalogs = @document.configuration_documents.pluck(:document_catalog_id)
      new_dcos = params[:document_catalogs][:id] - old_documents_catalogs 
      old_documents_catalogs = old_documents_catalogs - params[:document_catalogs][:id] 
      new_dcos.each do |dc|
        @document.configuration_documents.build(:document_catalog_id => dc)
      end
      ConfigurationDocument.delete_all(:document_catalog_id => old_documents_catalogs)
    end
    if @document.update_attributes(document_params)
      flash[:success] = "document updated"
      redirect_to @document
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
 end
```

If I leave the update like the normal scaffold. I get the error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass on `<%= fields_for (@configuration_document) do |dc|%>
```

**The relevant part of the "documents form":**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= fields_for (@configuration_document) do |dc|%>
      <%= collection_select(:document_catalogs, :id, @all_documents, :id, :name, {}, class: 'form-control')%>
     <% end %>
   </div>
```

I really know that is a lot of things. But basically, If I use version one of "create", I can create but no edit/update

If I use version two of the create, I can't create, edit/update.

Regards.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `update_attributes` has changed. What version of Rails are you using? How did you implement the `edit` action? Also, please edit your question to make it really clear what you are asking. Reduce to one version of code so we have a solid base for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= fields_for :configuration_document, @configuration_document do |dc|%>
```

The `field_for` method takes 2 arguments, the model, and the model object.  You were just missing the model.

In your first `create` method, you're using this:

```
params[:document_catalogs][:id].each_line do |document|
```

and I believe that what you really want is this:

```
params[:document_catalogs][:id].each do |document|
```

In the second `create` method, you're using this:

```
params[:document_catalogs][:id] = params[:document_catalogs][:id].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i)
params[:document_catalogs][:id].each do |document|
```

and I think that you really want to use this:

```
params[:document_catalogs].reject(&:empty?).map(&:to_i).each do |document|
```